# вызов функции при закрытии окна PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Нужно *вызвать функцию при закрытие второго окна*. Но она вызывается когда закрывается 1-ое окно. Как это исправить?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_first1(object):
    def setupUi(self, first1):
        first1.setObjectName("first1")
        first1.resize(380, 249)
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(first1)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 80, 191, 71))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.retranslateUi(first1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(first1)

    def retranslateUi(self, first1):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        first1.setWindowTitle(_translate("first1", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("first1", "first windows"))

class Ui_second2(object):
    def setupUi(self, second2):
        second2.setObjectName("second2")
        second2.resize(394, 300)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(second2)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 120, 191, 71))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        app.aboutToQuit.connect(self.closeEvent) # as I understand its bind close button

        self.retranslateUi(second2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(second2)

    def retranslateUi(self, second2):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        second2.setWindowTitle(_translate("second2", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("second2", "second windows"))

    # need print text when user close second windows, but print when close firs windows
    def closeEvent(self):
        print("close")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    first1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    second2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_first1()
    ui.setupUi(first1)
    first1.show()
    ui1 = Ui_second2()
    ui1.setupUi(second2)
    second2.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [signal] void QCoreApplication::**aboutToQuit**()
>
> Этот сигнал излучается, когда приложение собирается выйти из основного цикла событий,
> например когда уровень цикла событий упадет до нуля.
> Это может произойти либо после вызова quit() изнутри приложения,
> либо когда пользователь завершит весь сеанс рабочего стола.
>
> Этот сигнал особенно полезен, если вашему приложению требуется очистка в последнюю секунду.
> Обратите внимание, что в этом состоянии взаимодействие с пользователем невозможно.
>
> Примечание: это частный сигнал. Он может использоваться в сигнальных соединениях,
> но не может быть передан пользователем.

Мне показалось,что в вашем приложении использовать сигнал `QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit()`
как бы незачем. Как  вариант:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_first1(object):
    def setupUi(self, first1):
        first1.setObjectName("first1")
        first1.resize(580, 449)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(first1)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 40, 191, 71))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.retranslateUi(first1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(first1)

    def retranslateUi(self, first1):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        first1.setWindowTitle(_translate("first1", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("first1", "first windows"))

class Ui_second2(object):
    def setupUi(self, second2):
        second2.setObjectName("second2")
        second2.resize(294, 200)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(second2)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 120, 191, 71))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
#        app.aboutToQuit.connect(self.closeEvent) # as I understand its bind close button

        self.retranslateUi(second2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(second2)

    def retranslateUi(self, second2):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        second2.setWindowTitle(_translate("second2", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("second2", "second windows"))

 
class SecondWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_second2):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__(parent, QtCore.Qt.Window)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.parent = parent
       
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print("close SecondWindow и вызвать функцию ") 
        self.parent.my_func("Hello World")
        
        

class FirstWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_first1):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.second = SecondWindow(self)  
        self.second.show()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print("close FirstWindow ")
        
    def my_func(self, text):
        print(text)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = FirstWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: can I use its in logic file?